# How to debug the openjdk9 by netbeans8.2 in win10?

Tags: jvm, gdb, jvm-hotspot

When I tried to debug the openjdk9 by netbeans8.2 in win10, I got the following error:

```
"\"D:/jdk9/jdk9/build/windows-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/jdk/bin/java.exe\": 
not in executable format: File format not recognized"
```

How can I fix it?

I  build the source code by command `"./configure -with-freetype=/cygdrive/c/freetype -enable-debug -with-target-bits=64"`, then run `make all`, I also tried `slowdebug`, however, that also failed.

[image]

If I "run" the project instead of "debug", it runs successfully like below, so there is no issue for the file `windows-x86_64-normal-server-fastdebug/jdk/bin/java.exe`, it seems the `gdb` doesn't recognize the `java.exe` file.
[image]

Also I opened the `openjdk` source code from the location `D:/jdk9/jdk/common/nb_native` by `netbeans`, see below:
[image]

And tried to build it by `netbeans`, however, it produces the following error:

```
cd 'D:\jdk9\jdk\common'
sh ../configure --with-freetype=/cygdrive/c/freetype --with-debug-level=slowdebug --with-target-bits=64
/cygdrive/d/jdk9/jdk/configure: /cygdrive/d/jdk9/jdk/common/autoconf/configure: No such file or directory
PRE-BUILD FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 743ms)
```

I know that both paths `/cygdrive/d/jdk9/jdk/configure` and `/cygdrive/d/jdk9/jdk/common/autoconf/configure` exist.

This is how I configured the pre-built commands:
[image]

Comment: Try to build `"-with-target-bits=32"` instead of `64`, or check that you installed `64-bit` `gdb`.

Comment: Yes,It wouldnt get that exception after changing to gdb64, however it cannot stop at the breakpoints , I have no idea if I used the wrong way to importing the sources . you ever mentioned import the source by "find nbproject configuration inside your openjdk repository and import it into the NetBeans" ,I saw the config files configurations.xml and project.xml , however I didn't find the way to import them into netbeans directly , so I import the source by open the folder common/nb_native which I described in question , if this way to import source code is ok? BTW, I'm  ok to mark your answer.

Comment: BTW, I  built the source code in the Cygwin64  instead of by the NetBeans itself.

Comment: I set the breapoints in class classLoader.cpp, and I verified that the same breakpoints worked correctly  when I did debug by visual studio.

Comment: BTW, I installed the 64-bit gdb by Cygwin64 ,and I tried to build the source again by netbeans itself, however I always failed, you can see the error info in the end of the updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you build the openjdk `-with-target-bits = 64`, then make sure that you installed a 64-bit `gdb`, or build the openjdk in 32-bit mode.
2. Your steps to import the `nbproject` looks [correct](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/discuss/2016-February/003875.html).
3. Change `Build => Pre-Build` properties:

   Set "Working Directory" to `../..`

   Set "Command Line" to `sh ./configure ...`